# Hot wire won't stay in back outlet hole

Tags: receptacle

[image]

Replaced a regular outlet with a 4 USB plate. Mistakenly removed the side screw and now it won't hold at all, and the hole on the back won't hold the hot wire (since the side screw that is now stripped should have tightened it in place).

How can I get the hot wire to stay tight?

Comment: Sorry to say you ruined the device. As RGB said below, replacement is your only option.

Answer (score 7):

I'd replace the receptacle, loose wires can cause arcing or heating, which is the way fires get started.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the receptacle have 2 screws on each side?  Put both wires on the other screw.   If it's the screw-and-clamp variety as you seem to describe, it may allow 2 wires under 1 screw via the clamp method.  Otherwise, *pigtail* it.

If you've never done a pigtail, then replacing an outlet may be a bit too ambitious for you right now.  Skill comes with experience, but it helps to call in a friend to get that experience.

Comment: How many holes does it have for back-wiring on each side, two or four (on each side)? If it has only two, can one wire be side wired (looped around the screw) and the other wire be back-wired into the hole for that screw?